# I want translation of introduction about my selves in German langu.

Tags: translation, english-to-german

My name is xxxx. I am from xxx (city). i have completed my graduation in mechanical engineering from xxx university. i am 2014 batch passed out. present i am working in xxxx company as an engineer.my hobbies are playing football, watching movies.

Please help me to translate the above paragraph in a simple words of German with grammar for my interview.

thanks in advance

Comment: How can we **help** you other than performing the actual translation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ich heisse xxxxx. Ich komme aus xxx. Ich habe ein Diplom der Universität xxx in Maschinenbau. Ich habe mein Studium per 2014 abgeschlossen. Ich arbeite für xxx als Ingenieur. Meine Hobbies sind Fussball und Kino.

Comment: What exactly means "bach passing out" ?

Comment: which is formal way of telling our name - mien nama ist xxx (or) ich heisse xxxx

Comment: @Deepa: "Ich heisse" ; PS: "Mein Name" - nicht "mien nama". You probably heard this from spoken dialect "min namä" or also "min nama" ;)

Comment: Ist das "per" ein Rechtschreibfehler? "mein Studium **per** 2014 abgeschlossen"